# 3D secure authentication iframe height

Tags: iframe, standards, usability, opayo, 3d-secure

I've recently implemented 3D authentication into my checkout using an iFrame as part of a Sage Pay integration. I've then made live payments using my UK bank cards  (Lloyds & HSBC) and can see that the bank's authentication page for 3D authentication fits snugly into a 400px X 450px iFrame.

Now it seems that there is a problem pattern with DE users struggling to pass 3D authentication and in one example (see below) I was provided with, I can see that the scroll bar has become active. It occurs to me that they might have missed some part of the bank's authentication page by mistake by not scrolling down.

My question is; Is there a general rule of thumb for the size of an iframe when displaying a bank's 3D authentication page? Also, in this case the client has requested we remove the default iframe border, from a usability stand point, do you think this makes it more difficult to spot that there is more to the page?

Here is the DE example of a customer's bank asking for 3D authentication. I don't know if there is more to scroll down to as I only got the screenshot later on and am not familiar with this bank's authentication page;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have set the iFrame width to 100%.

Maybe this would stretch the text and it might fit.

If all works out it might get better with 3DSv2 next weekend as we can set the dimensions for the challenge window:

```
Dimensions of the challenge window that has been displayed to the cardholder.
The ACS shall reply with content that is formatted to appropriately render the
challenge UI in this window, to provide the best possible user experience. 
Preconfigured sizes are width x height in pixels of the window displayed in the
Cardholder browser window.

01 = 250 x 400
02 = 390 x 400
03 = 500 x 600
04 = 600 x 400
05 = Full screen
```

I don't see a border on my iFrame:

```
<iframe src="/URL.aspx" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Your screenshot is for 3DSecure v1 SagePay protocol 3.0, right?

Comment: I use the iFrame within a Modal. It's not ideal for phones, but it might make it more clear that one has to scroll.

Comment: I was curious about the border and found that you can set a class like class="border-0" (Bootstrap 4.3.1 = { border: 0 !important; } )